# Python groupby agg List with additional field calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe like this, I would like to groupby Col1 and Col2, and get Agg list for Col4 and average Col5 to the list, thank you.

```
    Col1  Col2        Col3    Col4    Col5
0   A     09/09/2021  1       Blue    5
1   A     09/09/2021  2       Blue    2
2   A     09/09/2021  3       Red     1
3   A     09/03/2021  1       Red     1
4   B     09/05/2021  1       Yellow  7
5   B     09/05/2021  2       Red     2
6   B     09/05/2021  3       Yellow  2
7   C     09/01/2021  1       Red     2
8   C     09/01/2021  2       Red     2
9   C     09/03/2021  1       Red     4
10  C     09/03/2021  2       Red     10
11  C     09/03/2021  3       Blue    2
```

I would like to see two dataframes

tried:
`df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'],as_index=False).agg({'Col4':(lambda x: list(x.unique()))})`
but can't get the average Col5 attached

version 1

```
    Col1  Col2        Col3    Col4         Col5
0   A     09/09/2021  1,2,3   Blue,Red     3.5,1
1   A     09/03/2021  1       Red          1
2   B     09/05/2021  1,2     Yellow,Red   4.5,2
3   C     09/01/2021  1,2     Red          2
4   C     09/03/2021  1,3     Red,Blue     7,2
```

version 2

so from version 1, I wanna see the aggregated list be on seperate columns for each records, and not having Col3 in version 2, so

```
0 A 09/09/2021 1,2,3 Blue,Red 3.5,1
```

turning into

```
0 A 09/09/2021 Blue, 3.5, Red ,1
```

and if a record has many aggregated list such as

```
Blue, Red, Yellow, Black 2, 3, 23, 3
```

then additional 8 fields will be added to become

```
Blue, 2, Red, 3, Yellow, 23, Black , 3
```

version 2 's expected output would be looking like this

```
    Col1  Col2        Col4     Col5    Col6    Col7
0   A     09/09/2021  Blue     3.5     Red     1
1   A     09/03/2021  Red      1
2   B     09/05/2021  Yellow   4.5     Red     2
3   C     09/01/2021  Red      2       
4   C     09/03/2021  Red      7       Blue    2
```

Comment: It's unclear what is the expected output

Comment: version 1 and version 2 are expected outputs

Comment: I provided an answer for version 1, the logic of version 2 is still unclear to me

Comment: What exactly is your question? Would be helpful to get your main question in the beginning of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a double `groupby`:

```
(df.astype({'Col3': str})
   .groupby(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col4'], sort=False, as_index=False)
   .agg({'Col3': ', '.join, 'Col5': 'mean'})
   .astype(str)
   .groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'], as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
)
```

Output:

```
  Col1        Col2         Col4     Col3      Col5
0    A  09/03/2021          Red        1       1.0
1    A  09/09/2021    Blue, Red  1, 2, 3  3.5, 1.0
2    B  09/05/2021  Yellow, Red  1, 3, 2  4.5, 2.0
3    C  09/01/2021  Yellow, Red     1, 2  2.0, 2.0
4    C  09/03/2021    Red, Blue  1, 2, 3  7.0, 2.0
```

##### version 2:

```
(df.astype({'Col3': str})
   .groupby(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col4'], sort=False, as_index=False)
   .agg({'Col3': ', '.join, 'Col5': 'mean'})
   .sort_values(by='Col5', ascending=False)
   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']).cumcount())
   .pivot(index=['Col1', 'Col2'], columns='n', values=['Col4', 'Col5'])
   .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis([f'Col{i+4}' for i in range(d.shape[1])], axis=1))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  Col1        Col2    Col4 Col5  Col6 Col7
0    A  09/03/2021     Red  1.0   NaN  NaN
1    A  09/09/2021    Blue  3.5   Red  1.0
2    B  09/05/2021  Yellow  4.5   Red  2.0
3    C  09/01/2021     Red  2.0   NaN  NaN
4    C  09/03/2021     Red  7.0  Blue  2.0
```

Comment: for Col3 and Col4, how would it be done, if I wanna it be acsending ordered, like 2    B  09/05/2021  Red, Yellow  2, 1, 3  2.0, 4.5 being 09/05/2021  Yellow, Red  1, 2, 3  4.5 2.0

Comment: You can `sort_values` before converting to string. Please update the question with the details, comments are bad for posting code/data.

Comment: okay, I will give a try, thank you, any idea on the version 2?

Comment: Not with more details on the logic, you should clarify the question. Do you want the max per intermediate group?

Comment: sorry for not providing the details on the logic, so from version 1, I wanna see the aggregated list be on seperate columns for each records, and not having Col3 in version 2, so 0 A 09/09/2021 1,2,3 Blue,Red 3.5,1, turning into 0 A 09/09/2021 Blue, 3.5, Red ,1, and if a record has many aggregated list such as Blue, Red, Yellow, Black 2, 3, 23, 3 then additional 8 fields will be added to become Blue, 2, Red, 3, Yellow, 23, Black , 3

Comment: Can you [add those details in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74953401/edit)?

Comment: That's a great solution on version 2, thank you!